# What gives better performance: name__iexact=name or name=name.lower() in Django?

Tags: django

I'm trying to decide if I want to use `name__iexact=name` or `name=name.lower()` in a filter query. What gives better performance? If I'm storing name always as lowercase.

The strings are not bigger than 10 characters if that matters.

Comment: Unless you've screwed up your database, database is faster than code.

Comment: Does a `LIKE` perform like a `WHERE =` query?

`string.lower()` is `O(n)`, in fact, `~O(10)` since `len(name)` is always less or equal 10.

Comment: @mu_is_too_short I don't really worry, it's just a curiosity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing name=name.lower() would perform better as you're only doing the lowercasing once (or it would not be needed since you mention you already stored it in lowercase) and then comparing with equality in the DB

Doing name__iexact=name will be a little slower as the ORM will perform a "LIKE" instead of "=", thus evaluating whether it matches for upper or lower case on each row.

Comment: Yeah, thinking about this problem and actually commenting on my question made me realize that, but since you answered it you get the win.